# Backwards progress bar (countdown)

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer, uiprogressview

I would like to take a UIProgressView and link it with an NSTimer (20s) and have the progress bar "countdown" smoothly with the timer. It seems that the information I have found on this isn't quite agreeing with me.

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What part can't you figure out? Making it go backwards? How a timer works?

Comment: Yes, I've tried linking the two unsuccessfully. I know how a timer works, but I am new to the progress view, so I don't really know how to make it go backwards _or_ forward.

Comment: You shouldn't use a progress bar for something like a countdown. It's a _progress bar_ not a "countdown bar". Users will be likely confused when it runs backwards.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper They won't be confused if it's part of a quiz. I'm attempting to make it a visual aid to show users that time is running out to answer a question, not show them "backward progress"

Answer (score -1):

Have your NSTimer call a function, with

```
#define TIMER_INTERVAL 0.05f

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:TIMER_INTERVAL
    target:self
    selector:@selector(timerMethod:)
    userInfo: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]
    repeats:YES];
```

And then in your function, update your UIProgressView based on the userInfo property of the NSTimer, like so:

```
-(void) timerMethod: (NSTimer *)timer
{
    float progress = timer.userInfo.floatValue;
    [progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];

    if (progress <= 0.0f)
        [timer invalidate];
    else
        timer.userInfo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:(progress - (1.0f/20.0f)*TIMER_INTERVAL)];
}
```

Comment: Mono guy or just typos?  (`.Invalidate();` and `NumberWithFloat:` and `if (float <= 0.0f)`)

Comment: Typos. Yup. Just typos.